# Adding django site to apache2 on ubuntu when already hosting rstudio and rapache

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I've built a django site for managing some of the data rstudio and rapache use.  I'd like to deploy it to the same box, either on a different port or on a different directory, but my knowledge in this area is a day old and the documentation combined with experimenting have not yielded results.

When I try to access the link `http://internalboxname:8000`  or `http://internalboxname:8000/django` it eventually says the page can't be returned.  The apache error log does not contain any details.

I'm hoping that someone can point me to the crucial bit of documentation I missed, and/or tell me where I'm going wrong

---

**Background**

I have a setup like:

- Rstudio set to port 80 using its conf file
- Rapache running on the sites-enabled/000-default VirtualHost (contents included below)
- Created file sites-enabled/django VirtualHost (contents included below)
- django project at /usr/local/.../python/app
- A wsgi.py file created by the app generation process in /usr/local/.../python/app

Installed versions:

- Ubuntu 12.04LTS
- Apache 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.6
- python 2.7
- libapache2-mod-wsgi 3.3-4build1

**sites-enabled/000-default** (most of this was already here, only changes I made were port number and /RapacheInfo location)

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

<Location /RApacheInfo>
SetHandler r-info
</Location>

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**sites-enabled/django**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/.../python/app/app/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /usr/local/.../python/app/app   
<VirtualHost *:8000>

<Directory /usr/local/.../python/app/app>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Implement [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)!
2. Configure apache so that the python path is outside the virtual host
3. Update wsgi.py to reference virtualenv path

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
WSGIPythonPath /usr/local/django-user/app/:/usr/local/django-user/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName localserver
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/django-user/app/app/wsgi.py
AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /usr/local/django-user/app/static/styles/$1
Alias /static/ /usr/local/django-user/app/static/
        <Directory /usr/local/django-user/app/app>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow #Apache version dependent
        allow from all #Apache version dependent
        </Files>
</Directory>
...
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/usr/local/django-user/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/app)
sys.path.append('/app/app)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/usr/local/django-user/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an Apache erro page?

Did you try including the *WSGI* directives insde the *VirtualHost* tag?

Comment: No error page and adding to the directive inside results in a configtest fail and it says that it can't be included inside a virtualhost

Comment: It should work fine accordingly the docs: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide Maybe you should set a ServerName

Comment: In the Apache config?

Comment: Yes, inside <VirtualHost *:8000>

Comment: Adding a value like `ServerName internalboxname` didn't work to resolve error of `WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section`